# Haskell Compiled IO-Action order and Flushing

Tags: haskell, io, stdout, monads

I'm encountering strange behaviour with IO, within compiled Haskell code. Here's what's going on:

```
-- MyScript.hs
main = do
    putStr "Enter your name: "
    a <- getLine
    putStrLn (a ++ " - that's a nice name!")
```

I run this in GHCi by calling `main` and it works as one would expect, first printing `Enter your name:` and then doing whatever it's to do afterwards. However, when I compile it with GHC (With and without `--make`), it first prompts for a line, and *then* prints everything at once, like this:

```
$ ./MyScript
Jimmy Johnson
Enter your name: Jimmy Johnson - That's a nice name!
```

To clarify, I want it to occur in the following sequence:

```
$ ./MyFixedScript
Enter your name: Jimmy Johnson
Jimmy Johnson - That's a nice name!
```

Could someone explain why this happens as it is, and how to sequence the IO the way that I would expect it to.

Note also that I've tried changing the first line of the `do` statement to `_ <- putStr "Enter your name: "`, but that still doesn't work.

Comment: This is due to buffering not ordering of io actions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The IO actions are happening in the correct order, the problem lies in how input and output pipes work. The string `"Enter your name: "` is written to the output buffer by `putStr` before the `getLine`, but the buffer hasn't necessarily been flushed. Adding `hFlush stdout` after the `putStr` will flush the buffer.

```
import System.IO

-- MyScript.hs
main = do
    putStr "Enter your name: "
    hFlush stdout
    a <- getLine
    putStrLn (a ++ " - that's a nice name!")
```

Comment: Wow, I had a thought that that might have been the case, but I didn't believe Haskell would actually obey a stateful thing like flushing stdout...

Comment: @AJFarmar: In this case, Haskell just gives you a pretty direct interface to the same underlying pipe abstraction as other programming languages. Since it's tucked away inside `IO`, it can just replicate the behavior exactly.

Comment: And I imagine GHCi flushes automatically?

Answer (score 4):

I have the exact same problem today, and it appears that it worked well when I was using `putStrLn` but stopped when I changed it to `putStr`. As other people said, it's not related to Haskell or GHC but how IO are flushed. According to the `System.IO` [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#12) there are 3 buffering mode :

- line-buffering: the entire output buffer is flushed whenever a newline is output, the buffer overflows, a System.IO.hFlush is issued, or the handle is closed.
- block-buffering: the entire buffer is written out whenever it overflows, a System.IO.hFlush is issued, or the handle is closed.
- no-buffering: output is written immediately, and never stored in the buffer.

The default buffering mode is said to besystem dependent, but it seems that normal program are in `line-buffering` mode, whereas GHCI is in `no-buffering` mode. This explain because using `putStrLn` or `putStr` will flush or not.

To solve your problem, you can use `hFlush stdout` to flush explictitey  (see Cirdec answer) or change the buffering mode once by doing `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering`. Obvioulsly the `NoBuffering` mode is not optimal but is probably enough for small toy program.

Comment: The handle for `hSetBuffering` is the first argument. `hSetBuffering :: Handle -> BufferMode -> IO ()` so setting `NoBuffering` on `stdout` would be `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering`.